# Tree-chromatic number and Hadwiger number

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph. For any set $X$ we set $[X]^2 := \big\{\{x,y\}: x\neq y \in X\big\}$. If $T$ is a tree, then a map $W: V(T)\to {\cal P}(V(G))$ is called a *tree-decomposition* if

- $V(G) = \bigcup {\text{im}}(W)$, and $E(G) \subseteq \bigcup\{[W(t)]^2: t\in V(T)\}$, and
- if $t_1, t_2\in V(T)$ and $t$ lies on the path in $T$ between  $t_1$ and $t_2$, then $W(t_1)\cap W(t_2) \subseteq W(t)$.

If $T$ is a tree and $W$ is a tree-decomposition, we say that the chromatic number of $W$ is the maximum of $\chi(W(t))$ over all $t \in V(T)$; and
$G$ has **tree-chromatic number at most $k$** if it admits a tree-decomposition with chromatic number atmost $k$. Let us denote the tree-chromatic number of $G$ by $\Upsilon(G)$.

It is easy to see that $\Upsilon(G) \leq \chi(G)$, and if $K$ is a clique in $G$, we have $|K|\leq \Upsilon(G)$.

Let $\eta(G)$ be the *Hadwiger number* of $G$, that is the maximum size that a complete minor of $G$ can have.

Is it true that $\Upsilon(G) \leq \eta(G)$ for all finite graphs $G$?

Comment: Can you give an example where $\Upsilon(G)$ exceeds the maximum size of a clique?

Comment: What is ${\mathcal P}(V(G))$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov - it is the power set (set of all subsets) of the set of vertices $V(G)$ of $G=(V,E)$.

Comment: @monkeymaths - I think some triangle-free graph $G$ with $\chi(G) > 4$ should do, but I have to check. Good question. I got the concept $\Upsilon(G)$ from the following paper but am not very familiar with it yet: https://web.math.princeton.edu/~pds/papers/treechi/paper.pdf

Comment: @monkeymaths The random graph construction of graphs with large girth and high chromatic number also have high tree-chromatic number.  This is not completely obvious, but follows from (1.1) of the above linked paper of Seymour.